# How I can replace linux module which are the same version?

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, kernel, kernel-module

I have `compat-wireless` module, it's built and patched.

I really need to replace the module located in `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/` with this one but I don't know how do this correctly.

Before, on a 2.6 kernel I just built this module from source and install it. But now, the module is in the kernel and there are many directories associated, so I need your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running `make install` from the directory where you built the module? Have you created a `<module name>.ko` file when you built the module? Did you try copying that to `/lib/.../wireless/`?

Comment: No, I think if I do make install (or checkinstall) it's maybe incorrect, because this module are in kernel now. The problem is the .deb packet that I've previously build for 2.6 and 3.2 (from backports) kernel has many directories and files (not only .ko), http://pastebin.com/6HqYaY7F.

Comment: OK, I see. In any case, `make install` will copy the files to their destinations and overwrite whatever is there. As long as what you have compiled works, there should be no problem.

Comment: Get it to working. Firstly moved old .ko, then make and checkinstall --fstrans=no, fstrans is needed to create 'update directorie in /lib/modules', without this option installation will (may) fail.

Comment: Cool, please post your solution as an answer and accept it to help the next person with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it to working. Firstly moved old .ko, then make and checkinstall --fstrans=no, fstrans is needed to create 'update directorie in /lib/modules', without this option installation will (may) fail.